# I want to set my checkbox on "checked" when i click a specific td in my table

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, jquery-click-event

Hei guys.
I want my Checkbox to be "checked" after i click the last td field of a row.
I tried it with JQuery but unfortunately i always checked all checkboxes.
I just want to check the td at the row i clicked.

Thats how i build my table.

```
<table class="table table-striped" id="notfallTable">
    <tr>
        <th value="name">Name</th>
        <th>Nachname</th>
        <th>Nummer</th>
        <th>Abteilung</th>
        <th id="thCheckbox"><button id="checkAll" class="btn btn-success">Check all</button>
        </th>
   </tr>
</table>
$.getJSON("NotfallSMS.json", function(data){
    var items=[];
    var checkbox="test";
    $.each(data, function(key, val){
        items.push("<tr>");
        items.push("<td contenteditable>"+val.Name+"</td>");
        items.push("<td contenteditable>"+val.Nachname+"</td>");
        items.push("<td contenteditable>"+val.Nummer+"</td>");
        items.push("<td contenteditable>"+val.Abteilung+"</td>")
        items.push("<td class='check'><input class='check' type='checkbox'>"+""+"</input></td>");

        items.push("</tr>");
    });
    $("<tbody/>", {html: items.join("")}).appendTo("table");
});
```

I hope you can help me out.
Greetings 
Elfdow

Comment: Where is the function that actually tries to set the checkbox? (also, `input` is self closing: `/>`, no need to use `</input>`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this you can hook a click event handler to the `td.check` elements which uses `find()` to retrieve the checkbox within the cell and toggles its `checked` property, like this:

```js
$('tr td.check').on('click', function() {
  $(this).find(':checkbox').prop('checked', (i, checked) => !checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped" id="notfallTable">
  <tr>
    <th value="name">Name</th>
    <th>Nachname</th>
    <th>Nummer</th>
    <th>Abteilung</th>
    <th id="thCheckbox"><button id="checkAll" class="btn btn-success">Check all</button>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td contenteditable>val.Name</td>
      <td contenteditable>val.Nachname</td>
      <td contenteditable>val.Nummer</td>
      <td contenteditable>val.Abteilung</td>
      <td class="check"><input class="check" type="checkbox" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td contenteditable>val.Name</td>
      <td contenteditable>val.Nachname</td>
      <td contenteditable>val.Nummer</td>
      <td contenteditable>val.Abteilung</td>
      <td class="check"><input class="check" type="checkbox" /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

However it's worth noting that you can achieve the exact same behaviour without JS or jQuery by using CSS instead. Wrap the checkbox in a `label` and use CSS to set it to `display: block`:

```css
label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped" id="notfallTable">
  <tr>
    <th value="name">Name</th>
    <th>Nachname</th>
    <th>Nummer</th>
    <th>Abteilung</th>
    <th id="thCheckbox"><button id="checkAll" class="btn btn-success">Check all</button>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td contenteditable>val.Name</td>
      <td contenteditable>val.Nachname</td>
      <td contenteditable>val.Nummer</td>
      <td contenteditable>val.Abteilung</td>
      <td class="check"><label><input class="check" type="checkbox" /></label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td contenteditable>val.Name</td>
      <td contenteditable>val.Nachname</td>
      <td contenteditable>val.Nummer</td>
      <td contenteditable>val.Abteilung</td>
      <td class="check"><label><input class="check" type="checkbox" /></label></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.check').on('click', function() {
    $($(this).find('input')[0]).prop('checked', true);
}
```

And remove the check class from the input